# MaxEnt error java.util.NoSuchElementException

Tags: error, java, ascii, maxent

I am new to using MaxEnt (and Java) and after selecting my presence-only data in .csv and my environmental variables in .asc, when I try to run the analysis, I get this error message:

> Error reading file C:\asc\bathy.asc:java.util.NoSuchElementException

[image]

I don't know if it means that Java doesn't find my files in the direction I told it because they are there and they open perfectly on QGIS or on a txt reader.

What can I do here?

Comment: Please [Edit] the question to place the error message in the Question body as text. Images are not legible on all devices, nor searchable by others.

Comment: Thank you for the advice